# What is this mysterious 'Form1' on my task view

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have hit Win+Tab to open Task View. While viewing the open windows, I found this:

[image]

A closer look:

[image]

Here, there is a mysterious windows named 'Form1'. It seems like a Blank .NET Windows Forms application. When I click it, it flashes (Appears for a second and then Disappears). Also it starts everytime when I log in to my computer.

Do you have any idea what is it?

Comment: Right click on it in Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc) and select Open file location to identify it. Are you a .Net developer?

Comment: It does not appear in Task manager. Yes, I am high school student and I am learning .NET and C#.

Comment: Form1 is the default name of the main window for a windows desktop program. Most of the time you would rename it, but hey.... Anyway, you should be able to identify the file with Process Explorer, running as admin. it has a cross-hair icon you can click and drag onto a window to jump to its processes.

Comment: Strange! Go to Details tab and search for it. Also check the Startup tab. Maybe it is one of your old projects.

Comment: @FrankThomas great! One more question, if I create a new winforms application namex 'Form1' and start it, will my desktop ne scrambled?

Comment: @AmirSinaMashayekh found it with FrankThomas help.

Comment: Good work! And you can create one thousand apps named Form1 and start them without any problem. Just it will be hard to distinguish them! ;-)